How to prevent re-render causing app to automatically go back to previous screen when the state of previous screen gets updated?
I am developing a react-native application, where one screen displays the list of users, and another displays list of messages. When a user clicks on one of users, they go to message screen. While in message screen, if new user joins, it automatically goes back to users screen. The two screens are on the same stack. How to stay on message screen when users state of previous screen changes ?
//_layout.tsx
// a part of code
<Stack.Screen name="home" />
<Stack.Screen name="chatpage" />

In home screen, each user are displayed as button. When new user joins, list updates
const activeSocketUsersList = useSelector((state: RootState) => {
     return state.socketReducer.users;
   });

const [activeSocketUsers, setActiveSocketUsers] = useState<any>(activeSocketUsersList);

When user press the button, it navigates to chatpage
// part of a flatlist with list of buttons

onPress={() => {
    // store.dispatch(setUser(item.userID));
    router.navigate({
    pathname: "/chatpage",
    params: {
    users: JSON.stringify({
    from: socket.id,
    to: item.userID,
        }),
       },
     });
   }}
    >
    <Text style={{ color: "#00f" }}>{item.userName}</Text>

In chatpage, it shows list of exchanged messages, and input and button to send new message.
While in chatpage, if new user joins, it goes back to home screen to display updated list of users.
How to get updated list, while also keeping user in chatpage ?

The code had socket event listeners in the global app/_layout.tsx file. It was updating global redux store state as new user joined. There was a useSelector hook to listen to new users, and the flatlist, displaying user list, updated accordingly.
The listeners for new users connection and disconnection was moved to app/homepage.tsx from app/_layout.tsx, and instead of them updating global users list in redux state, they simply updated local state of user list.
   const onUserConnects = (user: any) => {
      // store.dispatch(adduser(user));
      setActiveSocketUsers((u: any) => [...u, user]);
    };

    const onUserDisconnects = (user: any) => {
      // delete from active users
      // store.dispatch(redUserbyID(user));
      setActiveSocketUsers((u: any) =>
        [...u].filter((v: any) => v?.userID !== user?.userID)
      );
      // console.log(user, "disconnects");
    };

The old existing users were however fetched from global redux state, and was managed by global listener in app/_layout.tsx.
So, even when new user joins, while current user in chatpage, there is no interruption to go back to homepage, and when user goes back, they can find new joined users.
In summary, managing the few concerned listener in home page, and dealing with local state with useState instead of global state with useSelector resolved my problem.
